# Compare WCHAR String with Const Char in C?

Tags: c, wchar

I have written a code in C which will use the Process32First() API to get information about the process. All the information is stored in the PROCESSENTRY32 structure defined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

pe32 is the name of the PROCESSENTRY32 structure.
process name will be: pe32.szExeFile

I can print it this way:

```
_tprintf(TEXT("Process name: %s\n"),pe32.szExeFile);
```

now, I want to compare the process name with a specific process like explorer.exe

this is what I am doing:

```
if(!wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, _T("explorer.exe"))
{
 perform some action here;
}
```

It does not work.

In MS Visual Studio 2008, the data type for szExeFile member of the PROCESSENTRY32 structure is: WCHAR tagPROCESSENTRY32::szExeFile[260]

So, I think it is a Wide Character String?

and explorer.exe is a normal character string (const char *), pointer to an array of characters.

how can I compare szExeFile with a normal string?

I find these data types quite confusing and I hope to understand them better with this example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your if to use wide string for `"explorer.exe"` as

```
if(!wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, L"explorer.exe")
```

ie use `L"explorer.exe"` to compare with wide string.

You can also settings in your VC project to use UNICODE character set, through *Project->Settings->Configuration Properties->General*.